# What is the lisp/scheme equivalent of pass or "do nothing"

Tags: scheme, lisp

I would like to do the following pattern in scheme:

```
if N > 0:
    pass
else:
    do-function()
```

Currently I have it mocked up as something like this:

```
(if (> N 0) pass?? (do-function))
```

What's the proper way to do `pass` or `continue` or `return` or `;` or whatever it is to 'do-nothing' in scheme, but keep it there as a placeholder so I know that it's intentional (rather than changing the `if` to `if not N > 0` or `if N<=0` etc.)

Comment: You can use `(values)` to return empty values. Or use `'()` or `#f` as a placeholder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just add a dummy expression of your liking,

```
(if (> n 0) '() (do-something))
```

or with sugar-coating,

```
(define pass '())
(if (> n 0) pass (do-something))
```

but there are constructs in both Common Lisp and Scheme that make the intention  clear without the clutter – `unless` and `when`:

```
(unless (> n 0) (do-something))
(when (<= n 0) (do-something))
```

If the branch isn't taken, the value is `nil` in Common Lisp, and unspecified (i.e. some implementation-dependent value) in Scheme.

Comment: R6RS and then R7RS included `when` and `unless`, but R5RS did not have them; it is easy enough to write the macros, though.

Comment: [Lisp style PDF](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~nau/cmsc421/norvig-lisp-style.pdf), page 13